# Problems writing to the registry while installing OpenOffice.org

Tags: windows-vista, installation, windows-registry, openoffice

During the process I end-up with:

> Error 1406 : could not write value BASISINSTALLOCATION to key \Software\Open Office.org\Layers\Basis\32.

That's not a typo, it's straight from the dialog box. Event viewer should also read the exact same message.

Apparently something is blocking the modification of a key in registry.

I tried disabling Spyware Blaster, XP-Antispy, Antivirus and Firewall. (With an Admin profile account.)

I will also try with right-clicking installer to raise privileges.

I'm working with Windows Vista Home Premium, UAC is already deactivated.

Any ideas? Help appreciated.

Comment: as a workaround, you may use the portable version of OOo which doesn't have to be 'installed': http://portableapps.com/apps/office/openoffice_portable

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are logged into an account that is a member of the Administrators group, if you have UAC turned on you may still need to run the installer with elevated privileges. Instead of double-clicking the installer, try right-click then run-as-administrator from the menu.